# Stochastic calculus with Hermite polynomials

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, hermite-polynomials

Context: [Introduction to SDEs, by Evans](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d66c/a1516e1a9a9247f94841ccfbb262cf26d5e4.pdf), page 72, first line.

The author first asserts

$$\frac{d^n}{d\lambda ^n}(e^{\lambda x - \frac{\lambda^2 t}{2}})|_{\lambda=0} = n! h_n(x,t)$$

and then writes

> > Hence
> >     $$e^{\lambda x - \frac{\lambda^2 t}{2}} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\lambda^n h_n(x,t).$$

Also, $h_n(x,t)$ (where $n$ is a non-negative integer) is defined as follows:
$$h_n(x,t):= \frac{(-t)^n}{n!}e^{x^2/2t}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^{-x^2/2t}).$$
My question is: how does the equation in the yellow box follow from the previous one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Taylor series in $\lambda$.

$$\begin{align*}e^{\lambda x - \frac{\lambda^2 t}{2}} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lambda^n\frac{f^n(0)}{n!}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lambda^n\frac{n!h_n(x,t)}{n!}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lambda^nh_n(x,t)\end{align*}$$